# How to display different component if JSON data is empty in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, dictionary

I have a react app using the wordsAPI (a dictionary api). I used an input form to get the users search term then using setState I create a state that shows the definition. My problem occurs when the user searches a word thats not in the api, making the json data returned empty. I have tried doing a conditional saying if the definition is not undefined then load the main data, else return "not found". This doesn't work once you search for another term because it isn't setting the state properly. How can I render a component showing the word isn't found if the json data is empty properly?

```js
 render() {
        if (this.state.displayDefinition !== undefined) {
            return <div>
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="searchWord"
                        placeholder="Search a Word"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
                </form>

                <div >
                    <h2>Search Results for: {this.state.displayWord}</h2>
                    <h3>Definition</h3>
                    <ol>
                        {this.state.displayDefinition.map(item => <li>{item.definition} ({item.partOfSpeech})</li>)}
                    </ol>

                    <h3>Synonyms</h3>
                    <ol>
                        {this.state.displaySynonym.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
                    </ol>
                    <h3>Antonyms</h3>
                    <ol>
                        {this.state.displayAntonym.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="searchWord"
                            placeholder="Search a Word"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
                    </form>
                    <h1>Not Found</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


--Result--

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
WordInfo.render
src/components/WordInfo.js:84
  81 | </ol>
  82 | 
  83 | <h3>Synonyms</h3>
> 84 | <ol>
     | ^  85 |     {this.state.displaySynonym.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
  86 | </ol>
  87 | <h3>Antonyms</h3>
```

Comment: Hi. What's the actual response from the API when you don't get a result? Is it an empty array, or an error? How are you initialising `this.state.displayDefinition`? If either of those answers are "it's an empty array" the array will always be defined, so you probably should check the length of the state instead: `!this.state.displayDefinition.length`, for example.

Comment: Hey, the response I get when searching for a word that doesn't exist in the WordApi is {success: false, message: 'word not found'}. And I set the initial state to an empty array. What do I initialize it with if not an empty array?

Comment: When I try !this.state.displayDefinition.length I get this error when searching for a word that doesn't exist: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')